# How to create a higher order DCG parser in Prolog?

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg, meta-predicate

I would like to have some more general parsers, like for example `paren` that would take a parser and wrap it with parentheses:

```
paren(Parser, Result) -->
  "(", some_magic_dcg_call(Parser, Result), ")".


:- phrase(paren(number, N), "(123)").
123
:- phrase(paren(someatom, A), "(a)").
a
```

I tried `call` and `dcg_call`, but they don't seem to solve the problem. How can I run an arbitrary parser inside another parser?

Comment: just call the top level production

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I would like to create a generic parser combinatior that would work for any given production

Comment: see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=highorder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution using `call` works in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

paren(Parser, Result) -->
    "(",
    call(Parser, Result),
    ")".

number(123) -->
    "123".

someatom(a) -->
    "a".
```

Tests:

```
?- phrase(paren(number, N), "(123)").
N = 123.

?- phrase(paren(someatom, A), "(a)").
A = a.
```

Comment: I must have made some other mistake. This indeed does the job

Comment: `Parser` should rather be a non-terminal that lacks an argument. But with `call//2` you are referring to a predicate lacking three arguments. Yes, it is almost the same, but ideally these two different uses should use different constructs. Not sure, but `phrase//2...` could be a way out.